# Detecting correlation between 2 groups of time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, multivariate-analysis

Imagine we wanted to discover potential correlation between 2 devices, and these devices are characterized by a number of individual metrics, each having their own time series.

For example a **single device** might have 3 metrics like this (Device A):

[image]

...and **another device** might have its own set of readings for the same metrics (Device B):

[image]

How might one discover the **correlation between these 2 devices**? Obviously this is more complicated than looking for correlation between 2 time series since each device has multiple time series. Are there techniques for finding the **correlation between 2 groups of time series**?

[image]

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Prediction? Control? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen To see if there is any dependency structure among devices. Are they all independent, or is their behavior correlated, such that some device depend on other devices.

Comment: CANONICAL CORRELATION ANALYSIS BETWEEN TIME SERIES: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.0557.pdf